# Freeing all malloc()-created pointers with one command?

Tags: c, free, malloc

Is there a one-liner that will free the memory that is being taken by all pointers you created using `malloc`s? Or can this only be done manually by `free`ing every pointer separately?

Comment: You may be looking for "memory arenas".

Comment: That's easy: `exit(0);`

Comment: thats what i wanted to say initially ^^

Comment: +1 for thinking about memory leaks (and/or being lazy :-))

Comment: `exit(0)` will do the trick, but of course then I can't execute any more code. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do that by creating some kind of "wrapper" around malloc.
(warning that's only pseudo code showing the idea, there is no checking at all)

```
void* your_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void* ptr = malloc(size);

    // add ptr to a list of allocated ptrs here

    return ptr;
}

void your_free(void *pointer)
{
    for each pointer in your list
    {
        free( ptr_in_your_list );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't sound like a good idea and I would certainly not do that, at least for general purpose allocation / deallocation. You'd better allocate and free memory responsibly when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [memory pools](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch08s05.html). These are data structures built to do exactly this.

One common implementation is in the [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/), which is used in the Apache web server, as well as other projects, such as Subversion.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` on it's own has implementation-defined behavior. So there isn't a necessity for it to keep track of all the pointers it has, which obviously puts a damper on the idea.

You'd need to make your own memory manager that tracks the pointers, and then provides a function called `free_all` or something that goes through the list of pointers it has and calls `free` on them.

Note, this sounds like a somewhat bad idea. It's better to be a bit more strict/responsible about your memory usage, and `free` things when you're done; not leave them hanging about.

Perhaps with a bit more background on where you want to apply your idea, we might find easier solutions.

Comment: AND THAT IS WHAT I SAID -.-'''' yes i could also include half a book in my answer but i personally like comments that are short and informative not loads of trash with 2 usefull informations . kthxbye

Comment: Half a book? I wish I had the patience to write half a book. "No, and here's why" is much more informative than "No". Also, if you want to get up in arms about it, *at least mine is readable*. :o

Comment: @n00b32: Rage-quit is only allowed here if you actually quit.  Save the tantrums for elsewhere.

Comment: "here is why" ? on it's own has implementation-defined behavior <-- everything has . Note, this sounds like [...] hanging about. you do not know if they are. maybe he needs it for a purpose ? You'd need to make [...] free on them. thats what i said but with 20x more words . i dont care how many downvotes i get. ill say what i think. my is also readable if it is not get rid of those cultural blocks youve created in your mind ;) @roger: do so. please. EOD (End Of Discussion) on my side. (It means i will no longer continue to respond to your rants .)

Comment: "Implementation-defined behavior" has a specific meaning from the language standard, it is not some vague term.

Comment: @n00b32: There's no cultural roadblock, people just don't enjoy bad grammar and spelling. You misunderstand what I mean by readable. I don't mean it's *possible* to read: is't eays ot swho poelpe cna rdae rlelay mdeses pu stfuf. What it means is it's *easy* to read. And good English is easier to read, for English readers, than bad English. That's all; I'm not trying to attack you, nobody wants to start some flame war.

Answer (score 1):

Check out dlmalloc

ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.h

look at the following functions

```
/*
  mspace is an opaque type representing an independent
  region of space that supports mspace_malloc, etc.
*/
typedef void* mspace;

/*
  create_mspace creates and returns a new independent space with the
  given initial capacity, or, if 0, the default granularity size.  It
  returns null if there is no system memory available to create the
  space.  If argument locked is non-zero, the space uses a separate
  lock to control access. The capacity of the space will grow
  dynamically as needed to service mspace_malloc requests.  You can
  control the sizes of incremental increases of this space by
  compiling with a different DEFAULT_GRANULARITY or dynamically
  setting with mallopt(M_GRANULARITY, value).
*/
mspace create_mspace(size_t capacity, int locked);

/*
  destroy_mspace destroys the given space, and attempts to return all
  of its memory back to the system, returning the total number of
  bytes freed. After destruction, the results of access to all memory
  used by the space become undefined.
*/
size_t destroy_mspace(mspace msp);

...

/*
  The following operate identically to their malloc counterparts
  but operate only for the given mspace argument
*/
void* mspace_malloc(mspace msp, size_t bytes);
void mspace_free(mspace msp, void* mem);
void* mspace_calloc(mspace msp, size_t n_elements, size_t elem_size);
void* mspace_realloc(mspace msp, void* mem, size_t newsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something called "arena allocation", where you allocate certain requests from a common "arena" which can be freed all at once when you're done.

If you're on Windows, you can use HeapCreate to create an arena, HeapAlloc to get memory from the heap/arena you just created, and HeapDestroy to free it all at once.

Note that when your program exit()s, all the memory you allocated with malloc() is freed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that unless you write your own defintion of `malloc()` and `free()`. You should probably call `myCustomMalloc()` instead of regular `malloc()` and you should be keeping track of all the pointers in some memory location and when you call the `myCustomFree()` method, you should be able to clear all the pointers that was created using your `myCustomMalloc()`. Note: both your custom methods will be calling `malloc()` and `free()` internally

By this way you can achieve your goal. I am a java person but I use to work a lot in C in my early days. I assume that you're trying to achieve a common solution where memory is being handled by the compiler. That has a cost of performance as it is seen in Java. You dont have to worry about allocation and freeing the memory. But that has a severe effect on performance. Its a tradeoff that you have to live with.